# Template priority in presence of perfect candidate

Tags: c++, templates

Why is the "bad" template selected (second one) in this example, when the call signature matches perfectly (including constraint) with the other (desired) candidate ?

How can I fix it ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

#define Foo(...) FooT(__LINE__ __VA_OPT__(,__VA_ARGS__));

template<typename T> requires is_enum_v<T>
void FooT(unsigned line, T p1, 
          float m,       T p2, string errMsg = "")
{
  cout <<"good call"<<"\n";
}

template<typename... T>
void FooT(unsigned line, T... args){ 
  cout <<"bad call with "<< sizeof...(T) <<" args at line "<< line <<"\n"; 
}

int main(){
  enum myEnum : short { a = 0, b, c };
  //Foo(); // bad call
  Foo(a, 0.2, b, "error"); // good call
  return 0;
}
```

[play with this code](https://godbolt.org/z/1xvoz1EaT)

Comment: `0.2` is `double`, not `float`. `"error"` is `const char*`, not `std::string`. The first overload is not at all the "perfect candidate".

Comment: You're right. Can the first one be made to win with either float/bouble and/or char*/string ?

Comment: Add more template parameters for the other arguments, and more requirements to spell out exactly what you want the first overload to accept. Using `std::is_convertible`, perhaps.

Comment: In your question, it is not clear if the comment is what you want or what you get or if indicate if the expected function was called. I would have expected that the comment would indicate actual output.

Answer (score 0):

As per Igor's comment, the desired template is NOT a perfect match : `.2` is a `double`, not a `float`, and `"error"` is a `const char *`, not a `string`.

However this template answers the *intention* of the question : it is a better match than its variadic "fly trap" counterpart :

```cpp
template<typename T, typename T1, typename T2> 
requires is_enum_v<T> && is_convertible_v<T1,float> && is_convertible_v<T2,string>
void FooT(unsigned line, T p1, T1 m, T p2, T2 errMsg = ""){
  cout <<"good call"<<"\n";
}
```